# Solr Rest API issue - Java

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solr4

I have created new Rest API using solr 6.5 . Please find below steps
1. Custom Search Handler with query parameter

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="com.test.solr.TestSearchHandler" default="true">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="wt">json</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>
  <str name="fl">test1,test2</str>
  <str name="df">acSearch</str>
  <str name="sort">score desc</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>query</str>
</arr>
```

Custom class has below impmenetaion

```
   private ModifiableSolrParams createNewSolrParams(SolrQueryRequest request) {
    SolrParams oldParams = request.getParams();
    ModifiableSolrParams newParams = new ModifiableSolrParams(oldParams);
    setUpQueryExpression(newParams, oldParams);
    return newParams;
}


private void setUpQueryExpression(ModifiableSolrParams newParams, SolrParams oldParams) {
    String query = oldParams.get("query");
    newParams.remove("query");
    newParams.set(CommonParams.Q, query);
}
```

Its working for below url i am getting response

http://localhost:8330/autocomplete-service/core_autocomplete/select?query=test1:Airport*

But not working for below url

http://localhost:8330/nghp-autocomplete-service/nghp_autocomplete/select?query=Airport*

How to avoid key value pair in query

Working query=test1:Airport* 
Needed query=Airport*

Search is happening for word not for Phrase.
Example Airport is searching Airport India is now working.

Please let me know how to fix.

Comment: You should also post the source of your custom search handler `TestSearchHandler`

Comment: I suggest also to improve your question because is not clear exactly what is your target

Comment: How does your Airport data look like? Did you try queries like `Airpor*` ?

Answer (score 0):

Under your request handler, you're setting the default query to acSearch:

`<str name="df">acSearch</str>`

The handler will only search with that field in mind. I would get rid of this line entirely so that your request handler will have the full-text searching ability.

Comment: After removing <str name="df">acSearch</str> dynamic filed also not working.  Full text search is not happening. Its searching for word not sentence.

Comment: So the problem is when you search for: q=Airport* you only get documents that have Airport and not documents that have a phrase with Airport in it? (ex. Airport India)